# Shadowbox never activates; links only work as normal

Tags: javascript, object, flash, shadowbox

Following the official Shadowbox usage instructions, I appended just a few lines of CSS/JS:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
>
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
>
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox.css">
> <script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript">
> Shadowbox.init(
>   {players: ['img', 'swf', 'qt']} 
> );
> </script>
> </head>
> ```

With the pertinent HTML:

> ```
> <div id = "animations">
> <a href="gallery/animations/lipsync_websized.swf"
> rel="shadowbox[animations]; height=675; width=1200;"><img
> src="gallery/animations/lipsync_thumb.png" title="Lipsync Animation"></a>
>
> </div>
> ```

And yet, when I click on my thumbnail, it does not generate a Shadowbox overlay. Instead, my browser follows an ordinary link to the animation.

I've also tried Lightbox, Greybox, and Lightbox2,  working at this problem for about twelve hours. My understanding of Javascript objects and classes is very limited. Web Development is not my career path.

This question is rare on the Internet and answered threads even rarer. It must be something too basic.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code locally, and everything works fine for me. I wonder if you've included the "Flash (swf files)" player when downloading Shadowbox? That's the only thing that strikes out as being the problem

Comment: It's really encouraging to know it works for somebody.

When I downloaded the Shadowbox zip, I certainly did check that box. Also, even for the most basic Shadowbox function of displaying images, I have the same problem.

Moving the files around my web directory doesn't help, either.

Comment: Do you have an example of the page not working that you're able to link to?

Comment: I found the solution. It was so simple! Instead of moving files into my Shadowbox folder, I merely had to move the contents of my Shadowbox folder into the same folder with my HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you add special calls, Shadowbox files must be together with any HTML files make standard calls to the script.